# python setdefault(key,set())).update(... returns None

Tags: python, set, setdefault

I'm having a problem with setdefault and unions not working like I expect them to.  My code looks like:

```
    #!/usr/bin/python3.3
    kanjidic = {
        '恕': {'radical':{'multi_radical': {'口心女'}}},
        '靛': {'radical':{'multi_radical': {'亠宀月疋二青土'}}},
    }
    k_rad = {}
    for k,v in kanjidic.items():
        if 'radical' in v and 'multi_radical' in v['radical']:
            print (k, set(v['radical']['multi_radical']))
            k_rad[k] = k_rad.setdefault(k, set()).update(
                set(v['radical']['multi_radical']))
        print('>>', k_rad[k])
```

The print output looks like:

```
    恕 {'口心女'}
    >> None
    靛 {'亠宀月疋二青土'}
    >> None
```

If I substitute the two lines below for setting k_rad:

```
    k_rad[k] = k_rad.setdefault(k, set())
    k_rad[k].update(set(v['radical']['multi_radical']))
```

My output looks like this:

```
    靛 {'亠宀月疋二青土'}
    >> {'亠宀月疋二青土'}
    恕 {'口心女'}
    >> {'口心女'}
```

If I understand setdefault, (which obviously I don't) the output should be the same,right?
What am I missing?  Why am is `dict.setupdate(key,set()).update(set(...))` returning None?

As pointed out below, the problem is that update returns None.  I really didn't understand 
how update and setdefault work together.  Since setdefault sets the dict to the default if
we're creating a new dict element and returning the the hash and update updates the element
I didn't need the assignment.  All I really needed was:

```
    for k,v in kanjidic.items():
        if 'radical' in v and 'multi_radical' in v['radical']:
            k_rad.setdefault(k, set()).update(v['radical']['multi_radical'])
```

Thanks for the assistance!

Comment: It's not `setdefault`, `update` updates the set (returned by `setdefault`) in-place and returns None.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`dict.setdefault`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault) returns a set in your case. And [`set.update`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.update) is an in-place operation, which means it changes the original set and returns **None**. So if you assign the result to a variable you just assign it a **None**.

Comment: You may have a look at [defaultdict](http://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict).

Comment: I don't think this would work.  I don't know what I'm going to hit beforehand and I want to update a set so append won't work.